# update specific json inside array of jsons using mongoose

Tags: mongoose

i want to update specific json in array of array of jsons.
this is my document:

```
 [
   {"email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "password": "regherhrhrt",
    "name": "yosi levi",
    "partner": "nirit levi"
    "invites" [{
    "id" : 4,
    "status" : "Waiting"
    },
    "id" : 5,
    "status" : "Waiting"
    }]
   },
   { "email": "admin1@gmail.com",
    "password": "1234",
    "name": "yosi joha",
    "partner": "nirit joha"
    "invites" [{
    "id" : 6,
    "status" : "Waiting"
    },
    {
    "id" : 7,
    "status" : "Waiting"
    }]
   }
]
```

and i send in post the following json:

```
{
 "inviteEmail" : "admin@gmail.com",
 "id" : 4,
 "status" : "Accepted"
}
```

i need a code that update the mlab using mongoose.

Comment: Is this a specific array for a field inside a single document or a sample of the collection.

Comment: this is a sample of the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work:

```
var documentToUpdate = {
 "inviteEmail" : "admin@gmail.com",
 "id" : 4,
 "status" : "Accepted"
};

db.collection.update({"invites.status": documentToUpdate.id}, {$set : {"invites.$": documentToUpdate}}, function (error, res) {
    //Handle result
})
```

Comment: and if i want to update a whole invite, lets say my invite have more fields and i want to update like 5-6 fields, what should be the query?